# in spring mvc 3.1, how to have ExceptionHandlers for same exception for multiple profiles?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

For example, for same exception abc,  if it dev profile is active, I would have first method to handel it otherwise have the second one. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
        public @ResponseBody
        Object handleUnhandledExceptionForDev(Throwable t, HttpServletResponse res) {
            res.setStatus(500);
            .......
            resp.setError(t);
            return resp;
        }

    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
        public @ResponseBody
        Object handleUnhandledExceptionForProducion(Throwable t, HttpServletResponse res) {
            res.setStatus(500);
            logger.error(t);
            //resp.setError(t);
            return resp;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> You could try putting that logic inside the exception handler method.

Right, inject Environment and check the active profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting that logic inside the exception handler method.